# Setting SPSS 26 python to an Anaconda user-created environment

Tags: python, anaconda, spss

I want to link SPSS's python (Edit/Options/File Locations/Python installation) to an Anaconda user-created environment. The only thing I could figure out was to point SPSS to Anaconda install folder, and SPSS then uses the base environment.

Is there a way to make SPSS use another (user-created) environment ? I tried pointing SPSS to the new env's folder, but all I got was 'python installation not found'

Answer (score 0):

IBM SPSS Statistics has the ability to use an external python besides the one installed by default with the program.

Once you've installed that external Python, you should be able to point to it in the Statistics UI under "Edit -> Options -> File Locations".

Make sure you have the correct path to the python executable specified here.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of that, and I am already using Anaconda as SPSS' python. My question was about using various Anaconda environments, not about how to use Anaconda